# Is it possible to encrypt single directories?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt a single directory (or a group of directories) on a Mac? I don't mind if I have to use third-party software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X full-disk encryption, with Time Machine](http://superuser.com/questions/73181/mac-os-x-full-disk-encryption-with-time-machine)

Comment: I changed the question because I am really interested on encrypting a single directory, rather than creating a new partition, and encrypting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions below may be of use for you.

http://agilewebsolutions.com/knox

http://www.taoeffect.com/espionage/

Comment: Knox is a just a nice front-end to creating and managing encrypted Disk Images as is already easily possible with Disk Utility. I've used it for a while until a bug in its password handling code caused me to lose one of the containers.

Answer (score 4):

another third party solution is [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). I use it with OS X, Ubuntu and Windows.

TrueCrypt is open source.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeraCrypt

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have edited your question so that it now refers to encrypted directories, not volumes. While you cannot encrypt directories directly, as far as I know, you can use [encrypted disk images](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1578) to protect files on your hard drive without encrypting the entire drive.

Comment: I apologize for the change. I was taking the assumption it was not possible to encrypt single directories; when I saw the reply about File Vault, I remembered what I was first trying to do, and I changed the question.

Comment: You can also stick stuff in encrypted disk images, and then symlink it to a place outside the disk image! It'll show as a broken alias until you mount the disk image. (A symlink is effectively an alias that works with command-line programs; if you don't care about that, you can probably just use an alias.)

Answer (score 1):

For a third party solution I would recommend PGP whole disk encryption
http://www.pgp.com/products/wholediskencryption/index.html